# Show that $[0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}_l$ is not limit point compact

Tags: general-topology

I need to show that $X = [0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}_l$ in the subspace topology, where $\mathbb{R}_l$ is the lower limit topology, is not compact in the limit point definition, which is:

"a topological space $X$ is said to be limit point compact if every infinite subset of $X$ has a limit point in $X$"

So I need to show an infinite subset of $X$ which has a limit point not in $X$. I know that the open sets in $\mathbb{R}_l$ are of the form $[a,b)$. However, I can't imagine a subset of $X$ such that its limit poits are going to be outside it. It seems impossible.

Comment: How is the distance defined in $\Bbb R_l$? You won't be able to find a subset with a limit point outside $X$, but maybe you can find an infinite subset of $X$ with no limit points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Find an infinite subset of $[0,1]$ whose only limit point in the usual topology is $1$.

Comment: $1-\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @Gerlando: Yes, that will work.

Comment: Ok,  but I didn't understand how this will work for $\mathbb{R}_l$... $1-\frac{1}{n}$ will have $1$ as a limit point also in $\mathbb{R}_l$? This is still in $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{R}_l$, isn't?

Comment: @Guerlando: Look again: is $1$ actually a limit point of $\left\{1-\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ in the lower limit topology? Or can you find an open nbhd of $1$ that misses this set completely?

Comment: Hmmm, that's because I can only write an open of $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{R}_l$ in the form $[a,b)$? So i'd never be able to make $[0,1]$ in that topology?

Comment: * also I can write things in the form $(a,b)$

Comment: @Guerlando: I can’t make sense of your second question. As for your first, there are open sets in $[0,1]$ in the lower limit topology that are not of the form $[a,b)$: $[0,1]$ is such a set. It is the intersection of $[0,1]$ with the open set $[0,2)$ in $\Bbb R_\ell$, for instance. $\left[0,\frac14\right)\cup\left[\frac12,\frac34\right)$ is another. \\ A further hint: what is $[0,1]\cap[1,2)$? Is this an open set in $[0,1]$ with the lower limit topology?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Since this question is relatively old, I think there is no harm in revealing the answer. Wouldn't $[1,2)$ be a open neighborhood in $\Bbb{R}_\ell$ that misses set? Moreover, wouldn't this imply that, not only is $[0,1]$ not point compact, but $\Bbb{R}_\ell$ isn't either?